# Problema con dos subconsultas PHP MySQL SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

El caso es que tengo una tabla `pedidos`, dónde me interesan unos ean (`id`).

Y otra tabla `articulos_csv`, que también tienen ean (`id`).

Entonces, el tema está en que quiero ver qué ean (`id`) de pedidos están en la tabla `articulos_csv` y cuáles no.

Estoy usando como lenguaje PHP y como SGBD MySQL. Tengo hechas las siguientes consultas:

Para ver los ean de pedidos que no están en artículos_csv:

```
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv)";
```

Para ver los ean de pedidos que están en articulos_csv:

```
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos WHERE idarticulo IN (SELECT ean from articulos_csv)";
```

idarticulo en la tabla pedidos es el mismo campo que ean en articulos_csv.

El caso es que me devuelve resultados raros.

La tabla pedidos tiene 9270 campos.

Si ejecuto en SQL la sentencia del not in, me devuelve todos los campos, y si ejecuto la sentencia del in, me devuelve 8227 campos. No es posible.

Sin embargo, no veo dónde puede estar el fallo por ningún lado, ya que la sentencia parece correcta (MySQL no me arroja ningún error). Ni idea de dónde estoy fallando. Gracias, saludos.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

El código para ver los ean de pedidos que no están en articulos_csv:

```
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv)";
```

Devuelve 1043 resultados.

El código para ver los ean de pedidos que están en artículos_csv:

```
$sql="SELECT p.idarticulo FROM pedidos p, articulos_csv a WHERE p.idarticulo=a.ean";
```

Devuelve 8227 resultados. Esto así visto, tiene buena pinta, porque realmente la tabla pedidos tiene 9270 filas. Aquellos que están en ambas tablas en el campo tipo_articulo tendrán el valor "existe" y los que no el valor "nuevo". El caso es que hay filas que no tiene valor existe ni nuevo (null), y aquellos con valor nuevo deberían de meterse en otra tabla que se llama articulos_nuevos. Ahora mismo tiene 199 eans. Por tanto:

-Si 8227 están en ambas tablas, 1043 no, y hay filas sin marcar si es un artículo nuevo o existe, algo falla.
-Por otro lado, en articulos_nuevos hay 199 filas y no lo que debería de haber (1043 ahora mismo).

Por tanto, ¿dónde puede estar el fallo? No sé si es que estaré haciendo la sintaxis de sql mal, o por dónde puede venir el fallo, he estado revisando todo pero la verdad es que no lo veo. Gracias.

Comment: La segunda query petara falta el in

Comment: Vale, fue un cambio para ver si funcionaba, pero con el IN pasaba igual

Comment: Puede que haya `idarticulo` duplicados en la tabla...

Comment: Puedes chequear si hay duplicados con algo así: `SELECT * FROM pedidos GROUP BY idarticulo HAVING COUNT(idarticulo) > 1;`

Comment: Efectivamente hay duplicados, pero teóricamente está bien, porque en la BBDD puede haber varios idarticulo iguales pero para distintos pedidos. Por ejemplo, 10 personas pueden comprar el mismo producto (un móvil, por ejemplo). Al menos, me han confirmado que está bien que haya duplicados, aunque seguramente no sea lo más correcto. Al hacer ```SELECT p.idarticulo FROM pedidos p, articulos_csv a WHERE p.idarticulo=a.ean``` me devuelve 8227 filas. Pero no soy capaz de hacer el inverso, para que me de aquellos ean que están en pedidos pero no en articulos_csv.

Comment: entonces te hace falta una tabla con cardinalidad N:M que contenga estos pedidos

Answer (score 1):

La forma que yo he usado para realizar consultas para determinar cuales registros no se encuentran en otra tabla es con Left Join,

Un left join te regresara todos los registros de tu primer tabla y únicamente te regresara los coincidentes en tu segunda tabla, los no coincidentes te los enviara como nulos.

Y para determinar lo faltante validas en tu where que la columna principal de tu segunda tabla sea null.

Esta es la consulta como yo la determinaría.

```sql
SELECT idarticulo
FROM pedidos P
    LEFT JOIN articulos_csv A ON P.idarticulo=A.ean
WHERE A.ean is null
```

```php
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos P LEFT JOIN articulos_csv A ON P.idarticulo=A.ean WHERE A.ean is null";
```